# CM12 + Titanium = How to recover Contact data?

Tags: cyanogenmod, titanium-backup

I just installed `CM12` on N5110, and I made `Titanium` backup of all apps before. Now whenever I try to get my contacts back, the Contact app of android stops with error "`android.process.acore stopped`...

How to get the contacts? cause I didnt take google based backup on my contacts.

Thanks

Comment: Do you've the backup of Contacts Storage or Contacts Provider app? That app keeps the contacts in the database named contacts2.db. As long as the database is not corrupted, clearing data of that  app, restoring data from Titanium and rebooting should work. If not, then extract database from backup, force stop the app, go to app's data directory and replace the database there. Reboot and see what happens.

Comment: thats what i did... restore from titanium.. but the thing is that now with CM12, I have Contact 5.1, and old was Contact 4.1.2. So thats possibly one issue I guess..

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can (try to) restore your contacts manually.  (NOTE: I'm assuming a little bit of Linux knowledge.  I've tried to cover the things that are hard to look up, but little else.)

First, enable USB debugging mode, and plug your phone into your computer. Then,

1. Find the folder that contains your backups. By default, I think this is something like `/sdcard/TitaniumBackup`. If you used a custom location (e.g., to store backups on an external SD card), then it should be easy to find.
2. There should be a gzipped tarball with a name similar to `com.android.providers.contacts-<date>.tar.gz`. Copy it to your computer with `adb pull`.
3. Untar the file you just pulled. There should now be a folder called `data`. Descend into `data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/`. There you will find `contacts2.db` and `profile.db`. Use `adb push` to upload these to your phone. (Note: You will probably have to push them to a location that does not require root access.)

(For the next steps, you may want to reboot into recovery mode, to make sure that your phone is not using your contacts database.  You can do this easily using `adb reboot recovery`.)

4. Start a shell with adb again, and escalate to root using `su`. `cd` to `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/`. Rename `contacts2.db` to `contacts2.db.cm` and `profile.db` to `profile.db.cm`.
5. Copy the files you pushed to `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/`, so that they replace the ones you just renamed.
6. Make sure your new files have the same permissions as the old ones. Check the permissions of `contacts2.db.cm` and `profile.db.cm` with `ls -l`, and change the perms of your files with `chown`. Check the SELinux labels with `ls -Z`, and change them if needed with `chcon <full label> <file>`.
7. Reboot and see if it worked.

I hope this method works for you. I must admit, that when I tried it, CyanogenMod immediately reverted my changes (such that `contacts2.db` matched the original `contacts2.db.cm`). If this method does not work, and you *really* want to use CyanogenMod, then you can still recover the data from `contacts2.db` and try to add all of your contacts by hand.

1. Install `sqlite3`.
2. Run `sqlite3 contacts2.db`.
3. Your phone numbers are in the table named `phone_lookup`, and display names can be retrieved from the table named `raw_contacts`. You can see (at least some of) your contacts by running

`select raw_contacts.display_name, phone_lookup.normalized_number from raw_contacts 
    inner join phone_lookup on raw_contacts._id = phone_lookup.raw_contact_id;`